# What causes a directory to have permissions of d?????????, an owner of ?, a group of ?, and a time of ?, but a name?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux and Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to support programming languages that otherwise don't have good support on Windows. I've heeded [the advice to not create/modify Linux files with Windows tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). I keep all of the files that I want to edit in my editors/IDEs on Windows in `/mnt/c/Users/{username}/...` per that advice. So far, things have generally been good.

However, I wanted to remove a directory I was using for scratch. I've was unable to delete it from the Ubuntu Bash shell or the Windows Explorer interface. I first tried to `rm -rf` or `sudo rm -rf` from Bash and got no error output, but the directory persisted. I tried to `rm -rf` or `sudo rm -rf` the parent directory: `Directory not empty`. I tried to delete through Windows and got a dialog that says that I need to provide administrator permission. I do, so I get another dialog that says I need permission to perform this action. I tried to change permissions through the Windows Explorer as well as using `chown` and `chmod` and repeating the deletion steps without immediate success.

After going through the deletion process once on Windows and Linux, trying to change permissions/groups through both Windows and Linux, and trying to delete again, the directory persisted. However, when trying to respond to comments, the file was eventually deleted.

What causes this apparent invalid state and how can I prevent it in the future?

Comment: Is there anything in the directory? What are the permissions on the directory? (`ls -l dirname` and `stat dirname`). `rm -rf` shouldn't give directory not empty errors..

Comment: Can you include the directory listing in your question by using `ll /dirname` and pasting the output here?

Comment: @Seth Not sure what happened, but I just went back into the directory and it's now deleted. I guess after trying to delete in Windows and Bash several times, it's finally gone. I never even closed the shell. Just did an `ls -l lib` and got a not found error. Did an `ls -al` in the current directory and it was gone. Not sure if I should just delete this question or rephrase it to understand what happened. But everything is gone now, like I wanted.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the files being stored on a Windows controlled NTFS partition.. But I really don't know how the backend details work. That might be a line to edit your question around.

Comment: @Seth Perhaps. I took a stab at editing my question to focus on what happened and preventing it. It appears the standard Microsoft advice is to do what I'm doing. I haven't found much apparent in their [bug tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows).

Answer (score 1):

what you describe is the result of a corrupted file.  The most likely cause is a crash during file writing.  In a typical linux installation, you need to dismount the file system and run fsck.  For example:

```
umount /dev/sda5
fsck.ext4 /dev/sda5
```

If it's an xfs file system,

```
xfs_repair /dev/sda5
```

Since you are running ubuntu/bash on windows, you might need to run chkdsk in windows to clear up the error.  if the error disappeared without intervention, maybe windows detected the issue and repaired it during a boot.

Comment: Since he is using WSL, Unix filesystem repair commands will not work. It has to use Windows tools to repair them.